# Play Framework: Dependency Injection in Sub-Templates

Tags: dependency-injection, playframework, twirl

I want to use [Scala Templates Dependency Injection](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaTemplatesDependencyInjection).

Using it on the entry page it works:

```
@this(assets: AssetsFinder)
@(projConfig: ProjectConfig)

@main(projConfig) (assets){
  <h1>Sidebar</h1>

} {
  <h1>Home page</h1>
}
```

But if I want to this in a sub-template like main it does NOT.

```
@this(assets: AssetsFinder)
@(projConfig: ProjectConfig)(content:Html)

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>@projConfig.pageTitle</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        @content
    </body>
</html>
```

**Is this not possible or do I miss something?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify sub-template as a parameter in outer template's `@this` parameter list. For example, assuming full name of `main` is `views.html.main`, we have

```
@this(assets: AssetsFinder, main: views.html.main)
@(projConfig: ProjectConfig)

@main(projConfig) {
  <h1>Sidebar</h1>

} {
  <h1>Home page</h1>
}
```

Comment: thanks - still a lot of code - but at least the injecting code is separated now:).